# Connecting to AWS IoT using MQTT over Websockets from the backend

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt, aws-iot, aws-sdk-ios

I am trying to make a connection to AWS IoT from server side. I do not want to connect to AWS IoT through a browser client.

To provide more context, I have simulated a device (currently just a browser client) that takes an input and sends it through Websockets to my server. From there, I want to take that input, and send it through MQTT over websockets to AWS IoT (or another way).

There is no possibility that my client can directly go through MQTT over websockets, due to my device being restricted to only communicated through another protocol over Websockets.

Think of this like a protocol converter, or just tunnelling the received message from one socket and handing it to another.

(client)----sends message over ws----> (Server) ----sends message using MQTT --->(AWS IOT)

I hope this makes sense.
I have run quite a few examples successfully (my first snippet connects to the test.mosquitto.org), and have mqttjs and the AWS IoT sdk. At this stage I am just struggling to get the connection working correctly in the context of how I want to use it.

Any advice or input would be greatly appreciated.

My first code snippet is what I am currently attempting (and what I think will be most feasible)

```
var options = {
    clientId : 1,
    endpoint: 'xxxxxxxxxx.iot.xxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com',
    accessKey: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    secretKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    regionName: 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    debug: true
};


var client = _mqtt.connect('ws://xxxxxxxxxx.iot.xxxxxxxxxx.com', options);
//var client  = _mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org');

client.on('connect', function () {
    console.log("MQTT connected");
    client.subscribe('testing')
    client.publish('testing', 'Hello mqtt2')
})

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
    // message is Buffer
    console.log(message.toString())
    client.end()
})
```

This is one of my other failed attempts. At least this one provides an error.

```
var device = awsIot.device({
    keyPath: './certs/xxxxxxxxxx-private.pem.key',
    certPath: './certs/xxxxxxxxxx-certificate.pem.crt',
    caPath: './certs/root-CA.crt',
    clientId: 1,
    debug: true,
    host: 'xxxxxxxxxx.iot.xxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com'
});

//
// Device is an instance returned by mqtt.Client(), see mqtt.js for full
// documentation.
//
device
    .on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connect');
        device.subscribe('topic_1');
        device.publish('topic_2', JSON.stringify({ test_data: 1}));
    });

device
    .on('message', function(topic, payload) {
        console.log('message', topic, payload.toString());
    });
```

Here is the output/error

```
{ keyPath: './certs/xxxxxxxxxx-private.pem.key',
  certPath: './certs/xxxxxxxxxx-certificate.pem.crt',
  caPath: './certs/root-CA.crt',
  clientId: 1,
  debug: true,
  host: 'xxxxxxxxxx.iot.xxxxxxxxxx.amazonaws.com',
  keepalive: 300,
  username: '?SDK=JavaScript&Version=2.2.0',
  reconnectPeriod: 1000,
  fastDisconnectDetection: true,
  resubscribe: false,
  protocol: 'mqtts',
  port: 8883,
  key: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 52 53 41 20 50 52 49 56 41 54 45 20 4b 45 59 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d 49 49 45 70 41 49 42 41 41 4b 43 41 51 45 41 32 42 ... >,
  cert: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0a 4d 49 49 44 57 54 43 43 41 6b 47 67 41 77 49 42 41 67 49 55 53 33 ... >,
  ca: <Buffer 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 42 45 47 49 4e 20 43 45 52 54 49 46 49 43 41 54 45 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 0d 0a 4d 49 49 45 30 7a 43 43 41 37 75 67 41 77 49 42 41 67 49 51 47 ... >,
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true }
attempting new mqtt connection...
net.js:617
    throw new TypeError('invalid data');
    ^

TypeError: invalid data
    at TLSSocket.Socket.write (net.js:617:11)
```

Comment: Why does the server have to use websockets, why can't it use native MQTT?

Comment: The client to the server has to use websockets in this usecase.

Server to IoT (using MQTT) wouldn't have to. Unless I am misunderstanding something, I think my second code snippet is using native MQTT (which I can't get working either)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue!

I got the first proposed code snippet working:

- the clientId was not encapsulated in quotes
- I had not added a policy to my existing Thing on the AWS IoT console

I am still curious in regards to whether my second attempt is possible or not, so please do provide insight if you have any suggestions.